# letter variable without being defined works in Python

Tags: python

My code is this:

```
word = input('enter a word:')
for letter in word:
        print( letter)
```

Output:

```
enter a word:tree
t
r
e
e
```

Is `letter` an in-built variable?

Comment: no, you defined letter in the loop syntax. `for some_var in some_iterable:` makes `some_var` get bound to 1 item in `some_iterable` at a time. in this case, you have a string, so `letter` gets bound to 1 character in the string one by one.

Comment: @Paritosh_Singh thanks I tried it with a new variable and got the same.

Comment: yep, as expected. whatever name you give is being assigned under the wraps. that's how the for loop works.

Comment: Just to clarify: the characters of the variable word forms a list and then the variable letter accepts each word from the list and print it each time. Am I xorrect with the logic

Comment: Sorta, but not *quite*. `word` is a string. But in python, strings allow iteration. So you can think of them as *list-like*. The correct term for *list-like* would be iterables. Something that supports iteration (also known as looping) through it. The rest of it is fine in layman terms.

Comment: Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) to learn more about for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare variables in Python. The variable is defined in the for-loop directly. Python has only very few [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords). It is also not a [built-in constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#built-in-consts).

I recommend going through a [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). You might also want to try [exercism](https://exercism.io/tracks/python).

### Variable Annotations

The following stuff is only relevant for Python 3.6+. No matter which Python version you use, you can ignore it. If you are a very early beginner, you probably should ignore it.

You can use variable annotations to "declare" a variable. [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) introduces them. They look like this:

```
foo: str
int: bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Python is a language which doesn't require to declare variables beforehand, like Pascal or any versions of C. In the moment you use a new variable, it is considered as being declared. In your case, `letter` is declared in the `for` loop.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "interpreted language". Interpretation and compilation are traits of the interpreter or compiler (duh!), not the language. Every language can be implemented with an interpreter and every language can be implemented with a compiler. If English were a typed language, the phrase "interpreted language" would be a type error. Case in point: there are interpreters for C, and every current mainstream production-ready implementation of Python has a compiler (some even have more). By the way, ECMAScript does require variables to be declared.

Comment: No, we can not say "`letter` is declared in the `for` loop."

Answer (score 0):

`"Variables declaration"` in Python is implicit, in fact we better use `name binding`. There are many ways of `name binding` in Python, `for` is one of them.

For more details, you can have a look at [binding-of-names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names).

There is one very important implicit fact: **Python will pre-compute all names before executing code of one certain scope.**

```
def test_1():
    b = a + 1

def test_2():
    b = a + 1
    for a in range(3):
        print(a)

# NameError: name 'a' is not defined
test_1()

# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
test_2()
```

In `test_1`, when executing `b = a + 1`, the error is `name 'a' is not defined`.

In `test_2`, when executing `b = a + 1`, the error is `local variable 'a' referenced before assignment`. That is to say, in `test_2`, when executing `b = a + 1`, Python already knew that `a` is a local variable, it just has not been bound to an object, so the error is `UnboundLocalError`.